# Do vulnerability scans make sense for password protected websites?

Tags: security

Are vulnerability scans aimed at public facing websites or they can be run on password protected websites as well?

Comment: I think a little common sense should answer this for you without our help. Would you want to find any vulnerabilities in your site, even if it was protected with a password? What about a weak password vulnerability? What about a way in you missed? What about an exploit that can bypass your password?

Answer (score 1):

Generally there are two types of vulnerability scans Static and Dynamic.

**Static Scan:**
It is nothing but testing application from inside out by examining code, byte code or application binaries for probable vulnerability.

**Dynamic Scan:**
It is testing application from outside in by examining application in running state and trying to poke it in unexpected ways to discover probable vulnerability.

**Regarding Password protection -** 
Both of these scans asses password policies used in application. Most of the times static scan analyses for hardcoded passwords inside application, cryptographic mechanisms used in application. Also, dynamic scan assesses weak passwords which are easy to guess, etc. So, major part of password protection can be covered by using both of these scan. However, for more protection, we can rely on third party tools to analyze password policies configured in application.

Answer (score 0):

The scan will generally test your server as a whole, not just the website. It can see what other ports are open, which may indicate a vulnerability. The login page itself might have vulnerabilities.

An automated scan won't be able to spider the site and get all the pages, but that's usually not the point.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they work on both public, and private. Just like what user Garr Godfrey said, it will check the whole hosting server. So as long as the public facing side is on the same host as the protected side they do work the same way.

There are also tools that can yield information regarding a server besides port scans. These are usually known as (site) crawlers here is a link for one. 
https://portswigger.net/burp/help/spider_using.html